# Does ffmpeg support conversion of .psv video format to Mp4?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a .psv file like,

```
ffmpeg -i 0a02ec7f158a4f14914edda139230652.psv output.mp4
```

i get error,  `Invalid data found when processing input`.

Is this because ffmpeg does not support the .psv format or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Consider [submitting a feature request](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/) and providing a sample file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `ffmpeg` supports PSV, at least according to my web searches, and using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377300/what-are-all-codecs-and-formats-supported-by-ffmpeg) to check the formats supported (on my ffmpeg build from MacPorts).

Comment: having done some web searches myself i will go with your answer